# EmberJS 2.7 How to restructure/reformat/customize data returned from the store

Tags: json, ember.js, data-structures, ember-data, ember-router

I have what I think is a very simple issue, but I just don't get how to do this data manipulation. [This](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/reformatting-model-data-in-controller/8829/27) sadly didn't help, even though it's the same pain I am feeling with Ember.

Here is a route:

route/dashboard.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    // this is for testing, normally we get the data from the store
    model: function() {
        return this.get('modelTestData');
    },

    modelTestData: [{
        name: 'gear',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
            {y: 10, name: 'Test1'},
            {y: 12, name: 'Test2'},
            {y: 40, name: 'Test3'}
            ]
    }],

});
```

The structure of the 'modelTestData' object has to be exactly like that as it is passed into a child component that needs it structured that way.

I can easily get my data from the API and put it into the model:

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.get('category');
},
```

But then I need to restructure it...but how?

I have to somehow iterate over the categories collection and extract parts of data from each record to replace the 'data' part of the modelTestData object.

**So I have 3 issues I am completely stumped on:**

1. How to 'get at' the attributes I need from the model?
2. How to structure them as an array of objects with 'y' and 'name'?
3. How to assign that structure to the 'data' property of modelTestData instead of it being hardcoded?

Categories is a JSONAPI object like this:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "type":"categories",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Carrying system",
            "total-grams":"0.0"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "type":"categories",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Shelter system",
            "total-grams":"0.0"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to map the grams value to 'y' and the name to 'name' in modelTestData.

Note that the category data is used in other routes for other purposes exactly as returned by the API. So I don't want to change the model structure itself, or what the API returns...that will break other parts of the app that do use 'category' in its original structure.

This is a specific use case that this route needs to massage the data to pass to the child component as per the structure of modelTestData.

**I also wonder whether this data manipulation task belongs in a route?**

Should I somehow do this in the serliazer adapter, creating a new structure as say 'categoryWeights' so I can then do:

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.get('categoryWeights');
},
```

**EDIT**

I have managed to do this in the route, but it just gives me an array of objects. I need a single object containing 2 properties and an embedded array of objects.

```
   model() {
    return this.store.findAll('category')
        .then(categories => categories.map(category => {
            let data = {
                y: category.get('totalGrams'),
                name: category.get('name')
            };
            return data;
        }))
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably go into a computed property:

```
dataForSubModel: Ember.computed('model.@each.totalGrams', 'model.@each.name', {
  get() {
    return [{name: 'gear', colorByPoint: true, this.get('model').map(m => ({y:m.get('totalGrams'), name:m.get('name')}))}
  }
}),
```

The serializer is the wrong place, because its not that you need to convert it between the server and your app, but between your app and a strange component.
Actually the best thing would be to refactor the component.

Comment: I cannot refactor the component, since it's a 3rd party component. But yes you are right, it's between the app and the component, so this does seem to be the correct way to do it. Also much easier to understand what this code is doing than my own solution!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this to work in the route.

```
model() {
return this.store.findAll('category')
    .then( function(categories) {
        let data = [];
        data = categories.map(category => {
            return {
                y: category.get('totalGrams'),
                name: category.get('name')
                }
            });
        return [{name: 'gear', colorByPoint: true, data}];
    })
},
```

**I still have the feeling this should be done in the adapter or serializer. Would be happy to see answers that show how to do that.**